# how to do the opposite of mod in this equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, computational-mathematics

if $X=((A*Y)+C)\mod m$ how does one calculate $Y$? If you have all other variables except Y?
I have already tried everything I can think of just don't know how to do the exact opposite of mod, I can have any amount of answers.
X=43 A=13477813 C=1 and M=255

Comment: What are the values for A, C and m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as regular algebra,
until divisibility problems
caused by mod intervene.

In this case,
you get to
$X-C=A*Y\mod m$.
If $A$ and $m$
are relatively prime,
there is a $B$
such that
$A*B = 1 \mod m$.
Multiply both sides by $B$
so that
$B(X-C)=B*A*Y = Y\mod m$.

Comment: The only problem I have with that is that the C is also modulated